# How can I know if a user is active or inactive in Lotus Connections?

Tags: lotus, ibm-connections

How can I know if a user is active or inactive in Lotus Connections?

Thanks in advance,

Sunny Carrandi

Comment: How do you define "active" and "inactive"? Do you mean "logged in"?

Comment: No, I mean a user that can authenticate is active, one user that cannot authenticate is an inactive user. Exist a command in wsadmin console that tells me if a specific user is active on Lotus Connections?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on where you are coming from. If you are in the Web UI you should see the user grayed out and in some cases the word "**(inactive)**" after it.

In terms of the API, the namespace:
    `<snx:userState>`
is the indicator for an active or inactive user.

Answer (score 0):

User life cycle details - IBM Connections 3.0

> Useful data that people who have left the company contributed to IBM® Connections applications does not have to be removed; it can remain for use by others, but **the product user interface reflects the fact that the contributing user is currently inactive**.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/User_life_cycle_details_ic301

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Atom API http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/Getting_a_feed_of_all_user_profiles_lc3